# c++ Windows debug performance is very slow vs linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, performance, debugging

I have a Cmake OpenCV project. If I execute the same project under Windows in the debug configuration is the performance very bad and I place zero breakpoints. In the release modus, I get the same performance as on Linux.

Why is the performance better on Linux than on Windows? Can I fix the performance issue on window?

I use the compiler GCC on Linux and on Windows the VS compiler. On both OSs, I use Clion as IDE.

Comment: what do you call "performance"? BTW, on windows in debug, it fills all allocated buffers with 0xCC (AFAIR) may have huge consequences on you algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not uncommon to see 10..100+ slower performance between unoptimized and optimized code.

VC++ does more checks in Debug mode than GCC, which leads to easier debugging, but possibly slower code.

Some possible solutions:

- Enable *some* optimizations in Debug mode like `/Ob1`
- Disable [iterator debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/iterator-debug-level?view=vs-2019)
- Disable [debug heap](https://preshing.com/20110717/the-windows-heap-is-slow-when-launched-from-the-debugger/)
- Use *Release* mode and only [enable debugging in specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037662/how-to-make-msvc-debug-builds-run-faster)